# onPostExecute doesn't run

Tags: java, android

`onPostExecute` is not being called by the `ASyncTask.execute()` method

```
private class GetOneNews extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<News>> {

    @Override
    protected List<News> doInBackground(Void... params) {

        String newsid = getIntent().getStringExtra("NEWS_ID");
        News ter = APIProvider.NewsProvider.getOneNews(context, newsid);
        forReturn.add(ter);
        return forReturn;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<News> result) {
        oneNews.add(result.get(0));
        super.onPostExecute(result);}}
```

Comment: How have you confirmed `onPostExecute()` isn't being called? (i.e. have you used `Log`?)

Comment: Do you ever start the AsyncTask?

Comment: yes new new GetOneNews.execute();

Comment: Is it possible that APIProvider.NewsProvider.getOneNews throws an unchecked exception?

Comment: No. forReturn.add(ter); added news